# Groovy replace using Regex

Tags: groovy

I have varibale which contains raw data as shown below.
I want to replace the comma inside double quotes to nothing/blank.
I used replaceAll(',',''), but all other commas are also getting replaced.
So need regex function to identify pattern like "123,456,775" and then replace here comma into blank.

var = '
2/5/2023,25,"717,990","18,132,406"
2/4/2023,27,"725,674","19,403,116"
2/3/2023,35,"728,501","25,578,008"
1/31/2023,37,"716,580","26,358,186"
2/1/2023,37,"720,466","26,494,010"
1/30/2023,37,"715,685","26,517,878"
2/2/2023,37,"723,545","26,603,765" '

Tried replaceAll, but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to replace `","` with `""`, you have to [escape the quotes](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_double_quoted_string) this will do:

```
var.replaceAll(/\",\"/, /\"\"/)
```

If you want to replace commas inside the number strings, `"725,674"` with `"725674"` you will have to use a regex and [capture groups](https://regexone.com/lesson/capturing_groups), like this:

```
var.replaceAll(/(\"\d+),(\d+\")/, /$1$2/)
```

It will change for three groupings, like `"18,132,406"`, you will have to use three capture groups.